# Nattable - refreshing underlying data

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, nebula, nattable

We want to change some of our JFace TableViewers to NatTable. The TableViewer had a handy method to change a data sources namely:

```
tableViewer.setInput(source)
```

We used this method pass a new List when we queried a database. Is there something similar available in NatTable?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, in NatTable you work with implementations of `IDataProvider`. For your `List` case, you can use `ListDataProvider`.

There's a tutorial on NatTable on [vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html), with [a section on data provision](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html#dataaccess_dataproviding) which gives you an example of how to use `List` models with NatTable. That's a good starting point. NatTable has a fairly complex API and I don't want to repeat documentation.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not solve my issue. I cannot replace the underlying List or the ListDataProvider reference on-the-fly. @dirk-fauth pointed out in this question, that the best is to use .clear() & .addAll(List).

Answer (score 0):

NatTable visualizes data contained in a List. To exchange the data shown in a NatTable you typically create a ListDataProvider for the data access with a List instance that you can modify at runtime.

You would typically exchange the data via:

- create a list for NatTable -> natList
- load data from database -> dbList
- natList.clear()
- natList.addAll(dbList)

Dependent on whether you are using GlazedLists or not, you need to refresh the NatTable after the actions are done.

If you are using GlazedLists and the GlazedListsEventLayer you need to think about bulk updates by deactivating the GlazedListsEventLayer prior updating the data list content to avoid unnecessary event firing.

Comment: Thanks, so this means, instead of referencing to a new List object as we did at a TableViewer implementation, it is advisable to use.clear() & .addAll() on the underlying natList.

Comment: Exactly, that is the way to go with the current implementation. Alternatively you could try to extend ListDataProvider and add API to replace the underlying list at runtime. But if you use GlazedLists to wrap the original list IMHO the clear and add mechanism is better.

Comment: Have a look at the API GlazedListsEventLayer#deactivate() and GlazedListsEventLayer#activate()